# How do you run a cloud function at an interval?

Tags: firebase, scheduled-tasks, google-cloud-pubsub

I've been trying to do something along these lines:

```
export const refreshJob = functions.pubsub
    .schedule("every 1 minutes")
    .onRun(() => helloWorld());

export const helloWorld = functions.https.......
```

I'd like to run the `helloWorld` cloud function every minute, but can't seem to figure it out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up the HTTP-based Cloud Functions with scheduled Cloud Functions. They are independent from each other. Depending on the function of `helloWorld()`, the way forward differs.

#### HTTPS Callable Function

If your existing function is a HTTPS Callable function, that looks like:

```js
export const refreshJob = functions.pubsub
    .schedule("every 1 minutes")
    .onRun(() => helloWorld());

export const helloWorld = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // do the task
  // make sure to return a Promise
});
```

you would edit it into:

```js
export const refreshJob = functions.pubsub
    .schedule("every 1 minutes")
    .onRun((context) => {
      // do the task
      // make sure to return a Promise
    });
```

If you want your function to be callable AND run on a schedule, you could instead use:

```js
function handleHelloWorldTask(data, context) {
  // do the task
  // make sure to return a Promise
}

export const refreshJob = functions.pubsub
    .schedule("every 1 minutes")
    .onRun((context) => handleHelloWorldTask({ scheduled: true }, context));

export const helloWorld = functions.https.onCall(handleHelloWorldTask);
```

#### HTTPS Request Handler

If your existing function is a HTTPS Request handler, you would use:

```js
const FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG).projectId;

export const refreshJob = functions.pubsub
    .schedule("every 1 minutes")
    .onRun(async (context) => {
      const response = await fetch(`https://us-central1-${FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID}.cloudfunctions.net/helloWorld`);
      if (response.ok) {
        console.log('Triggered helloWorld successfully');
      } else {
        throw new Error(`Unexpected status code ${response.status} from helloWorld: ${await response.text()}`);
      }
    });

export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // do the task
  // make sure to call res.end(), res.send() or res.json()
});
```

Comment: Great!  Thank you!